# Game-loop profiling

Tags: java, optimization, profiling, game-engine, game-loop

I'm asking for help with profiling task. Task context is real-time MMO-game engine. Server run N game loops in parallel in M threads. 
What we need to determine:

1. How much time was spent on execution of each task in game frame (game frame is 1 iteration of game loop)
2. Which tasks were processed slower then threshold (threshold=100ms for example)

Comment: 1. what did you try. 2. here are sooo many questions about game loops. Im so sure that thats a duplicate

Comment: You shouldn't try to custom a solution in this case.  There are [plenty](https://profiler.netbeans.org/) [of](https://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html) [tools](http://jrat.sourceforge.net/) [out](http://www.khelekore.org/jmp/) [there](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/).